# Fold out list vertical and horizontal

Tags: jquery, html, css, list, fold

I have the following list, which I want to act in the following way:

- It's supposed to be clickable, then a vertical list has to appear.
- If you click an item in the vertical list, it has to appear horizontally with info about the item.
- I want all the items to be hidden until the user clicks either Test 1-4 or a submenu Test 1.1 - 1.5.

CSS & HTML:

```
<style>
    #navcontainer
    {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-bottom: 40px;
        border-top: 1px solid #999;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #navcontainer ul
    {
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: -8px;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    }

    #navcontainer li
    {
        display: inline;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 5px;
    }

    #navcontainer li a
    {
        padding: 1px 7px;
        color: #666;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    #navcontainer li a:hover
    {
        color: #000;
        border: 1px solid #666;
        border-top: 2px solid #666;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
    }

    #navcontainer li a#current
    {
        color: #000;
        border: 1px solid #666;
        border-top: 2px solid #666;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #666;
    }
</style>

<div id="navcontainer">
    <ul id="navlist">
        <li><a href="#" id="current">Test1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Test4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have tried to make it work with jQuery and "TextShower" - but I simply can't (I only know basic HTML)

Here's an image of my idea, I hope someone can make sense of it and help out, I'm sure the coding is quite simple, I just simply cannot get it to work :(

[image]

Comment: And where do you find "Test 1.1", "Test 1.2" etc and their respective texts?

Comment: I dno, they are supposed to be descriptions of a class with how long it takes and what it requires, so a short text. I was thinking it could just be writting in a div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign a CSS Class to each Test and Test Version.

```
/* hide by default */
.vertical_nav {
    display:none;
}

/* show */
.current {
    display:block;
}
```

Now you have more vertical menus, every one has the class `verical_nav`, therefore they are hidden.

```
<ul class="vertical_nav" data-test="1"></ul>
<ul class="vertical_nav" data-test="2"></ul>
<ul class="vertical_nav" data-test="3"></ul>
```

Also, you have all the links in the horizontal menu

```
<a href="#" class="test" data-test="1">Test 1</a>
<a href="#" class="test" data-test="2">Test 2</a>
<a href="#" class="test" data-test="3">Test 3</a>
```

additionally we assigned the `data-test` attribte, which help us to identify.

the idea is to select data-test=1 if the link with data-test=1 is clicked.

use then jquery (or pure js) to select a verical nav

```
$("a.test").click(function() {
    var testNumber = $(this).data("data-test");
    $(".vertical_nav").removeClass("current");
    $(".vertical_nav[data-test=" + testNumber + "]").addClass("current");
});
```

the same you can then do with the content block in the middle.

I wrote a little fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/87ypG/